# Pandas Max Min between index range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following time series pandas dataframe

```
index | Date | Time | open | high | low | close | volume

293  2018-06-14  14:55  1832.15  1833.40  1831.90  1833.35   37947
294  2018-06-14  15:00  1833.40  1834.95  1833.30  1834.90  106271
295  2018-06-14  15:05  1834.95  1835.05  1834.40  1834.85  102107
296  2018-06-14  15:10  1834.80  1834.85  1832.95  1833.80   95931
297  2018-06-14  15:15  1833.75  1834.85  1833.05  1834.85  124639
298  2018-06-14  15:20  1834.85  1834.85  1831.55  1832.50  121206
```

1. I need to fetch index and row data where Date='d1' and Time='t1'

   eg. fetch the row values where data=2018-06-14  and time=15:05
2. I need to find max(high) between t1 and t2 where date='d1'
   (t2>t1)

   e.g find max(high) between Time 15:00 and 15:15 where date = '2018-06-14'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fetch the row values where data=2018-06-14 and time=15:05

Using Boolean indexing:

```
mask = (df['Date'] == '2018-06-14') & (df['Time'] == '15:05')
values = df[mask]
idx = res.index
```

> max(high) between Time 15:00 and 15:15 where date = '2018-06-14'

Using Boolean indexing and `pd.Series.max`:

```
mask = df['Time'].between('15:00', '15:15') & (df['Date'] == '2018-06-14')
res = df.loc[mask, 'high'].max()
```

In both solutions, you will have to do some work to ensure you have the right data format (e.g. `datetime` / `timedelta`) and adapt masks accordingly. There are *many* questions on SO on this topic.